# What's the meaning of "spin it"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From NPR: [The Beatles' Yearlong Journey To 'The Ed Sullivan Show'](http://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=273085051)

> "She Loves You" wound up being released by the tiny Swan label out of Philadelphia in September, 1963. Bruce Spizer says the label tried to get Dick Clark to ***spin*** it. "American Bandstand" was broadcast nationally out of Philadelphia.

"She loves you" is a song of The Beatles.

What's the meaning of "spin" here? I even cannot find a proper meaning in the dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 60s, CDs didn't exist and we only had [vinyls that used to turn on a turntable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/File%3aDiamondDiscPhonograph.jpg). The records spun<sup>*</sup> on the turntables. DJs spun the records.

The sentence means that Swan, the label that had produced the Beatles'single, tried to have Dick Clark play (spin on his turntable) *She loves you* on his radio show "American Bandstand".

*She loves you* was first recorded an a [single](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/single#Noun) (noun 1) with a different B side [in the US](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_KYcnDFS019M/SXZDclvUECI/AAAAAAAABVA/u_mMo8NFRlY/s400/c+slyvars1.gif) and [in Britain](http://assets.catawiki.nl/assets/2/2/4/2/24210da0-0aca-012d-ac7d-0050569428b1.jpg).

---

<sup>*</sup> Past tense of spin. Although I've heard spinned used for vinyl records.

Comment: yes, you got it right. I misunderstood it with 'spin' as in my answer. Nevertheless, that too can go if Dick Clark was asked to smartly present a low-ranked track.

Comment: @Maulik: it's just we're probably from a different generation and some things are obvious to those who have lived them!

Comment: That's so kind way to inform me. Kudos! Upvoting your answer.